# Variables in linux shell script and user input

Tags: linux, shell

Hello I'm trying to make a short script that is supposed to take user input in the form of a file ending like .txt or .odt and type out how many files with that ending the directory contained.

So it looks something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter a file ending like .txt"
read ending
for x in `ls *$ending`; do
    echo "test"
done
```

Comment: You've virtually done it. Instead of the `for` loop, all you need is `echo There are $(ls -d *$ending|wc -l) files ending in $ending`. I have used $() instead of back-quote because I need back-quotes to indicate a code segment, and I have used `ls -d` in case any directories have the chosen ending. There are a couple of things wrong in the `for` loop of your example: (1) embedded blanks will cause extra iterations; (2) it is needlessly complicated - `for x in *$ending;` would give the same result.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a file suffix (like .txt): " ending
files=( *"$ending" )
echo "found ${#files[@]} files with that suffix"
```

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). This stores the filenames in an array, then prints out the size of the array.